# Not getting selected radio button value from one HTML form to another in Python Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I have a home page with radio buttons. I select an item (database type) and want to get the checked-value in python code and then after some validation want to display another form to connect to the selected database type. But after trying so many things, I am unable to get the selected-radio-button value and then unable to process conndb.html below. I am quite new to Python web development. Not getting anything working to meet this requirement. Home page pyhton code is

```
@bp.route('/')
def index():
db = get_db()
if request.method == 'GET':
    posts = db.execute(
            'SELECT id, DB_Tp'
            ' FROM DB_Type'
            ' ORDER BY DB_Tp ASC'
            ).fetchall()

    error = None
    if len(posts) == 0:
        error = 'No Database Type To Choose For Meta Data. Create New Entry'
        flash(error)

    return render_template('meta/index.html', posts = posts)
else:           **#=> from here the code is never executed. It always falls thru to next function**

    checked = request.form['dbtype']
    print("This is ", checked, flush = True)
    if checked == "MySql":
        return render_template('meta/conndb.html')
    else:
        error = "Nothing checked "
        flash(error)
        return redirect(url_for("meta.index"))
```

index.html is -

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block header %}
  <h1>{% block title %}Select Database Type{% endblock %}</h1>

{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
   <form class="post" action="/conndb">
{% for post in posts %}
    <label class="body">
    <input type="radio" name="dbtype" required>{{post['DB_TP']}}</label><br>
{% if not loop.last %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}    
    <button type="submit">Next</button>
</form>
<hr>
{% endblock %}
```

Depending on the selected radio button, I want to perform different operations with different kind of DB. After getting the value from the selected radio button, I render this template to connect to database...
conndb.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block header %}
   <h1>{% block title %}Provide Details To Connect To Database{% endblock %}</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
 <form method="post">
 <label for="host">Host Name</label>
 <input name="host" id="host" required>
 <label for="user">User ID</label>
 <input name="user" id="user" required>
 <label for="passwd">Password</label>
 <input type="password" name="passwd" id="passwd" required>
 <label for="db">Schema</label>
 <input name="db" id="db" required>
 <input type="submit" value="Get MetaData">
 </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"value" attribute is missing in radio html.

e.g.:

```
<input type="radio" name="dbtype" value="{{post['DB_TP'].id}}" required>{{post['DB_TP']}}</label><br>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Its still not working. I still get "TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement."

Comment: My browser shows something like this 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/conndb?dbtype=MySql' and goes to the conndb.html - which is perfectly fine. My problem is that I want to capture dbtype=MySql in my python Flask code before rendering the conndb.html template. Appreciate your input pls.

Comment: I guess this is a diff question, anyway: request.args.get('dbtype')

Comment: Thanks.  I got it working with your direction. appreciate it.